# Android Image Size Limitation

Tags: android, image, memory, imageview

So I seem to be running a problem on an Android program I'm writing. I'm still a noob, so please help me out understanding the problem and how I can solve my issue.
I'm creating a simple game and I'm doing all of the graphic designs for it. My images are 1024x1024 or 1024x512 with a resolution of 300 pixels/inches. Yes, I understand that I'm probably over doing it. I just want the graphics to be really clear and to look good. All of the graphics are in the drawable folder not in hdpi, ldpi, mdpi, xhdpi or xxhdpi drawable folders. Now, the problem I'm having is that my app was working fine until I added one more 1024x1024 image to the drawable folder. Now the app just crashes as it tries to load an image. The problem I get is memory over flow. It doesn't matter what activity is running, it seems that once it hits a limit of loading images it crashes. I read the android resolution page http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html but maybe my English is not good enough to understand.
Should I resize the images to each resolution (hdpi, ldpi, mdpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi)?
When I move from one activity to another activity in my app, do I have to clear the ImageViews in the previous activity to clear up memory?
Please help me understand how this work.

Thanks
David

Answer (score 4):

Ironically, the method you're using is probably making your images look worse.

When you place raster images in the root drawable folder, they are assumed to be `mdpi`, and will be scaled up for the other densities. This means that your 1024x1024 bitmap is scaled up and pulled in as a 2048x2048 bitmap (which in most cases is far larger than you probably need). So yes, your best bet is to make the images whatever size they need to be for a particular density, and create separate images in each drawable folder that you need to support.

Also to note, it doesn't matter what resolution (you mentioned 300 ppi) you set your images to, the only thing that matters is the pixel dimensions.

Comment: another solution is to put images to `drawable-nodpi` folder

Comment: True, if the scale of the image doesn't matter that's a good solution.

Comment: What's confusing me is that i don't know what density i need to support. I'm making my app to be supported by any screen size. All of the objects's sizes are calculated based on the phone's screen size. So i don't know what sizei should make my images. Does that make sense?

Comment: Are the images supposed to fill the screen?

Comment: The background image fills the entire screen, then I have other images that their sizes are calculated based on the height and width of the screen. So when I have the calculated height and width, I would create an ImageView and set the setImageResource using R.drawable.imagename id.
This was working fine until I added another image and then I started having the memory over flow errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got vm budget out of error.I faced this problem while working on my previous application. After searching i found solution from developers guide ... fallow this  [link](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) hope it solves your problem.Thanks